# How to get the first column from a json array using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have a json array in the below format:

```
[
  {
     "id":"01",
     "language": "Java",
     "edition": "third",
     "author": "Herbert Schildt"
  },
  {
     "id":"07",
     "language": "C++",
     "edition": "second"
     "author": "E.Balagurusamy"
  }
]
```

I want a result consisting only the first column from this array in the form:

```
[ "01", "07" ]
```

I tried many codes but wouldn't succeed, is there a way to achieve this using jquery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like following using `map()` function.

```
var input = [
    {
        "id": "01",
        "language": "Java",
        "edition": "third",
        "author": "Herbert Schildt"
    },
    {
        "id": "07",
        "language": "C++",
        "edition": "second",
        "author": "E.Balagurusamy"
    }
];

var result = $(input).map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get()

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for the same thing in plain javascript (adapted from acepted answer)...

```
var input = [
    {
        "id": "01",
        "language": "Java",
        "edition": "third",
        "author": "Herbert Schildt"
    },
    {
        "id": "07",
        "language": "C++",
        "edition": "second",
        "author": "E.Balagurusamy"
    }
];

var result = input.map(function(item)
{
    return item.id;
});

console.log(result);
```

Or in fancy ES6...

```
var result = input.map(item => item.id);
```